# One of your dependencies requires the .NET Framework

Tags: .net, uwp, frameworks, dependencies, nuget

When trying to run an UWP app that was working normally suddenly I get this error:

> One of your dependencies requires the .NET Framework, but the .NET
> Framework could not be found in the NuGet packages installed in this
> project.  Please install the appropriate .NET Framework packages
> required by your dependency.

Here is my "PackageReference"

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <Version>12.0.3</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.DBChooser">
      <Version>1.0.11</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp">
      <Version>2.80.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views">
      <Version>2.80.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Forms">
      <Version>2.80.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer">
      <Version>1.4.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials">
      <Version>1.5.3.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms">
      <Version>4.8.0.1451</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile">
      <Version>2.4.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms">
      <Version>2.4.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Dependencies

```
<Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you include the `<Dependencies>...</Dependencies>` from you `Package.appxmanifest`? this will show all your dependencies for your project. You may also look in your `*.csproj` file and post all `<PackageReference>...</PackageReference>`

Comment: There is not "Dependencies" tag, I just included the "PackageReference"

Comment: The dependecies are in your `Package.appxmanifest` file

Comment: Ok, I see, I just included the "Dependencies" tag

Comment: I installed this nuget package "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform" and worked, It compiles, but I have another issue when running: onecore\com\combase\winrt\error\restrictederror.cpp(1014)\combase.dll!757C3CD9

Comment: Could you please provide us more detailed information about this error? It would be better to show which line of code is wrong and provide the related code.

Comment: I have a demo blank project with the issue, Would you like to have the code?, if you say yes, how can I send you the code?, Google Drive public link?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the issue installing this nuget package:
"Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform"

[image]

but after installing I got an issue in this line:

```
if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

To solve this issue I removed this line:

```
Font="Bold,Verdana,Italic,24"
```

From labels:

```
<Label 
      Grid.Row="1"
      x:Name="txtForte"
      TextColor="White" 
      Text="Forte Editor" 
      HorizontalOptions="Center" 
      VerticalOptions="Center">
</Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed both Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform and
Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms.

After the latter, the dependency error went away. I don't know if the first package is needed or not.